# enable TCP in SQL server 2005 express edition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005-express

sorry for answer but how to enable TCP in SQL server 2005 express edition? I used configuration manager, find network configuration/protocols and there enabled TCP, after that I have restarted sql server service and tried installation of problematic software again (software which told me that TCP is not enabled) but I have the same problem :-(

Answer (score 5):

In Sql Server Configuration Manager.

1. Sql Server Network Configuration > Protocols for SQLEXPRESS
2. Select TCP/IP
3. Protocol Tab, Change Enabled
4. IP Address Tab, Section IPALL set the TCP Port to 1433
5. Restart Service.

To verify that it works, go to cmd

```
> netstat -an
```

and you will see

```
...
TCP    0.0.0.0:1433           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
...
```

Then try on cmd

```
> sqlcmd -U sa -S .\sqlexpress,1433
```

And you will be connected...hope so

*Remember to enable and start the Sql Server Browser Service

[Source](http://support.webecs.com/KB/a375/how-do-i-configure-sql-server-express-to-allow-remote.aspx)

Comment: don't understand why I have to provide the port manually, but worked! thx

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to SQL2005 Express edition over TCP/IP.

Did you open 1433 port on your firewall? Server should accept incoming connections on 1433 port.

After that enable TCP/IP in SQL Server 2005 Surface area configuration utility (see MSSQLSERVER > Database Engine > Local and remote connections > Using TCP/IP only)

Answer (score 0):

In express edition the TCP support is disabled, although you see the corresponding configuration. Either buy a commercial version of use another RDBMS.

Comment: oh really... I was under impression that it is just disabled as defalt setting but that you can make it enabled...